# Bug in XML syntax highlighting

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

Hi, I think I found a bug in XML syntax highlighting. It happens when a node contains /* or /** as text. I don't know why, but I cannot reproduce the issue here in this question, but you can check this out in this question of mine:

[Getting logged in users with a SessionRegistry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912149/getting-logged-in-users-with-a-sessionregistry)

[image: xml syntax highlight bug]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax highlighter uses the <s>default one-size-fits-all</s> Java version, since the question is tagged [java](/questions/tagged/java); it doesn't know that this particular snippet is XML. If you specify the language by adding

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
```

before the code block, it works fine:

```xml
    <property name="filterInvocationDefinitionSource">
        <value>
            CONVERT_URL_TO_LOWERCASE_BEFORE_COMPARISON
            PATTERN_TYPE_APACHE_ANT
            /**=httpSessionIntegrationFilter,logoutFilter,exceptionTranslationFilter,concurrencyFilter
        </value>
    </property>
```

See the "syntax highlighting" section in the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).